# Selecting individual data_types across mutliple tables using SQL and HQL from Oracle

Tags: java, sql, oracle, hql, oracle-sqldeveloper

**Hello World, Here is the situation,**

Basically instead of generating values from a table like like so

```
34.324,  09/13/2011, thankyou,
```

I would like to generate the type of that specific value

e.g

```
VarChar2, Date, varchar2(char 30)
```

Just to add another layer of difficulty a Java application pulls data from the multiple Oracle database tables using HQL. Thus I would need an equivalent HQL statement to the SQL statement (if it exists)..

I understand the DESC keyword lists the column data types for an entire table however as mentioned above I require specificity.

**In Summary**

I would like to reverse engineer this application to generate a report of the data_types of the data instead of the actual data itself. I could easily just manually walk through the code however they are over 200 entries and this will be a real pain.

Any help is truly appreciated. If this question is unclear please let me know and I will provide more details and examples.

Comment: use the system tables instead.  `Select * from all_tab_Cols where Table_Name = 'TableName' and Owner = 'SchemaName'` and pivot results as needed.

Comment: You will not be able to use DESC/DESCRIBE. It is not even SQL, it is a SQL*Plus function.

Comment: Just to clarify @JamesB I do have access to Desc